# Android Mobile App Database

Tags: android, database, mobile

I am new to mobile app development and thus have a few questions.

Currently I am in a team that is about to develop an android mobile application for the Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0) operating system. This application will enable the user to fill out profile information which gets stored in a database that is not on the phone. However, since the database stores private information from the user, it should be private.

The purpose of the app is to utilize the user's profile information in conjunction with information of a geographic area (terrain, climate, flora, fauna) in the United States from an online database in order to calculate how well they will be able to survive for a given amount of time.

I am planning on using the Android development tools plugin with the Eclipse IDE.

So I wanted to ask a couple of major questions:

1. What will I use from the Java development tools to add users and enter in their profile information to the database? In other words, what will I use in order to communicate with the database?
2. Since the application will be pulling information from an online database, it will need some way of transferring and using that information. What can I use to do this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

For both 1 and 2, you can develop web service that will allow android application to communicate with Remote database to either insert or retrieve or even delete records from database.

and here is a good Tutorial to give you clue how can you start doing so.[Click Here Please](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/)

Answer (score 0):

Read up on SQLite support for Android and how to make HTTP requests:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries you can look into.

For database interaction (locally), [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is nice. This gets you one step away from writing raw SQL, handles escaping for you, etc. It maps your database rows onto POJOs for you (as the name implies).

For the remote data, you'll want a REST (or SOAP? or ??) client.  It isn't clear whether the remote data store belongs to you, or if so, whether you've created it yet.  If it is already in place, you have less flexibility here.

The [Spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework) offers a couple [Android libraries](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) including one for consuming REST services and one for authentication. I have also seen mention of people having success with Jersey.

If you do go REST, then you will (probably) be dealing with JSON. [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation) and [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) are the two main contenders here. Both offer automatic (de)serialization between POJOs and JSON. I've used Jackson, and I will probably try Gson the next time around. While Jackson is nice, I found the documentation to be a bit fragmented and hard to follow. Ymmv.

My latest project uses a combination of ORMLite, Spring's REST library, and Jackson to pretty good effect.

The gist is this: define some model classes, annotate the classes and their fields with a few things from Jackson and a few others from ORMLite, point Spring at your endpoint.  Spring will retrieve the JSON, Jackson will parse it into model objects, and you can then use ORMLite to persist it to your local database. In the other direction, pull something out of your database (ORMLite hands you model objects), hand the model off to Spring, which uses Jackson to serialize the data before sending it out.